# React: questions about manipulating React states with framework-agnostic util functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a util function called `cycleThrough` that uses a generator to cycle through an iterable and can either go forward or backward.  (I am really bad at naming please feel free to suggest a better name)

```js
function cycleThrough(iterable, { startIndex = 0 } = {}) {
  let index = startIndex;
  const mod = (n, r) => ((n % r) + r) % r;
  const iterator = (function* () {
    while (true) {
      const dir = yield iterable[index];
      index = mod(index + dir, iterable.length);
    }
  })();

  return {
    getPrev: () => iterator.next(-1).value,
    getNext: () => iterator.next(1).value
  };
}
```

So if we pass `const array = ["1", "2", "3"];` as the `iterable` , then `getNext` would iterate through the array one by one and go back to the beginning i.e. `1` -> `2` -> `3` -> `1` -> `2`, vice versa for `getPrev` - `1` -> `3` -> `2` -> `1`

In a React component I want to display the current item of the array, and one button to go to the next item and another button to go back to the previous item. This is my implementation.

```js
function cycleThrough(iterable, { startIndex = 0 } = {}) {
  let index = startIndex;
  const mod = (n, r) => ((n % r) + r) % r;
  const iterator = (function* () {
    while (true) {
      const dir = yield iterable[index];
      index = mod(index + dir, iterable.length);
    }
  })();

  return {
    getPrev: () => iterator.next(-1).value,
    getNext: () => iterator.next(1).value
  };
}

const array = ["1", "2", "3"];
const { getNext, getPrev } = cycleThrough(array, { startIndex: 1 });

export default function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(array[0]);

  const onLeft = () => {
    const prev = getPrev();
    setCurrent(prev);
  };

  const onRight = () => {
    const next = getNext();
    setCurrent(next);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{current}</h1>
      <button onClick={onLeft}>left</button>
      <button onClick={onRight}>right</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It works ok and here is the live demo you can play with https://codesandbox.io/s/cycle-through-integration-in62o?file=/src/App.js

After that, I want to also cover the use case where `array` is not an external variable to the React component. Instead, it can be a remote resource that needs to be fetched from an API endpoint. So I use `useEffect` to kick off the network requests to fetch the `array` and keep a copy of it in the local component state. and then feed that state into `cycleThrough`.

```js
const fetchArray = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(["1", "2", "3"]), 2000));

export default function App() {
  const [remoteCount, setRemoteCount] = useState(null);
  const [remoteCountToDisplay, setRemoteCountToDisplay] = useState(null);

  const {
    getNext: getNextRemoteCount,
    getPrev: getPrevRemoteCount
  } = cycleThrough(remoteCount, { startIndex: 1 });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchArray().then((array) =>
      setRemoteCount(() => {
        setRemoteCountToDisplay(array[0]);
        return array;
      })
    );
  }, []);


  const onLeftRemote = () => {
    const prev = getNextRemoteCount();
    setRemoteCountToDisplay(prev);
  };

  const onRightRemote = () => {
    const next = getPrevRemoteCount();
    setRemoteCountToDisplay(next);
  };

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{remoteCount ? remoteCountToDisplay : "loading"}</h1>
      <button onClick={onLeftRemote}>leftRemote</button>
      <button onClick={onRightRemote}>rightRemote</button>
    </div>
  );
```

However the result was really buggy. The number seems to be jumping randomly. I thin it has something to do with `cycleThrough` getting invoked every time the component re-renders. But I cannot seem to find a workable solution to make the state, which is the `array` we fetched, work correctly with `cycleThrough`. Maybe I am using an anti-pattern by changing states from external utils? Not sure what are some of the best practices around this and any help is appreciated.

Here is a live demo you can play with for the second example. https://codesandbox.io/s/cycle-through-integration2-73trs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: "Naming things is one of the most difficult problems in computer science." - That bi-directional iterator is pretty nifty though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that `cycleThrough` is invoked every render cycle. You want to only call it if the `remoteCount` value updates. You can use the `useMemo` hook to memoize the returned handler values.

```
const {
  getNext: getNextRemoteCount,
  getPrev: getPrevRemoteCount
} = useMemo(() => cycleThrough(remoteCount, { startIndex: 1 }), [
  remoteCount
]);
```

You also had a bug in your codesandbox where you had wired the `getNextRemoteCount` handler to the `prev` in the `onLeftRemote` callback, and  `getPrevRemoteCount` handler to the `next` in the `onRightRemote` callback. This wasn't helping the "random" jumping around and general bugginess I'm sure.

[image: Edit react-questions-about-manipulating-react-states-with-framework-agnostic-util-fu]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it an anti pattern to manipulate React states with an external util function? Is a custom hook more suitable in this case?

Comment: Also I remember I read it somewhere that `useMemo` can be invoked multiple times even when the dependency list didn't change - React won't guarantee that it would only invoke it once until the dependency list changes.

Comment: @Joji React hooks are call each and every render cycle, it's only when a dependency changes that their callbacks are invoked. In the case of `useMemo`, only on the initial render or when the dependency updates will the hook recompute a value and then memoize it. It can be called a billion times, and if the dependency hasn't updated it simply returns the memoized value.

Comment: @Joji To answer your first question, no, I wouldn't consider it anti-pattern to manipulate state via any utility function, so long as you are updating state in the correct, normal React ways. I don't see an issue with your utility. In fact, as I said, I think it's pretty cool. A hook could/would be able to accomplish the same goal. Looks like the other answer does this, but it doesn't use your utility incrementor. To each their own. Memoizing the callbacks only required changing basically one line of existing code.

Comment: @Joji If I were to make a custom `useCycleThrough` hook from the `cycleThrough` utility I would just have if return the `useMemo` result, i.e. something like `const useCycleThrough = (iterable, { startIndex = 0 } = {}) => useMemo(() => cycleThrough(iterable, { startIndex }), [iterable]);`, called as `const { ..... } = useCycleThrough(remoteCount, { startIndex: 1 });`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hey Drew thanks so much for the answer. That totally makes sense. Just one quick question - I tried to use your approach with `useMemo` to modify my code so it looked exactly like what you had in your answer but it is still buggy. I couldn't figure it out why. Can you take a look at it please? https://codesandbox.io/s/cycle-through-integration4-t24k6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237931/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-joji).

Answer (score 0):

As Drew mentioned, you can use useMemo to fix this. But I suggested another method. Using hooks. This is simpler and more appropriate to React.

```
const useCycleThrough = (iterable, startIndex) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(startIndex);

  const goPrev = () => {
    setIndex((old) => (iterable.length + old - 1) % iterable.length);
  };

  const goNext = () => {
    setIndex((old) => (iterable.length + old + 1) % iterable.length);
  };

  return [iterable[index], goPrev, goNext];
};
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cycle-through-integration2-forked-csgcc?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yea I thought about the idea of making it a hook - I am familiar with hooks and when I first learned about Hooks I was always wondering when we need to make a util function a hook or just leave it as a pure util function. I guess a way to think about it is to see whether or not it manipulates or touches the states?

Comment: Another question - why is that we need to two separate states i.e. `index` and `value`. since we can use `index` to get the correct value it seems to me that we only need `index` state.

Comment: Yes, you are right `value` was unnecessary.